# HttpInterceptor request broadcast not running whilethe response broadcast does run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I am trying to create a laoding box in my angular application here is what I have so far:

This is the loadingBox directive:

```
   app.directive('loadingBoxDir', function (eventsSvc) {
    var loadingBoxDir = {
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/App/Infrastructure/Directives/loadingBoxView.html',
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            isLoadingBoxVisible: '='
        }
    };

    loadingBoxDir.link = function ($scope, $element) {
        var loadingBox = $element.find('.fa-spinner');
        var body = angular.element('body');
        var loadingBoxParent = $element.find('#global-spinner');

        loadingBox.css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": body.height() / 2 - loadingBox.height() / 2 + "px",
            "left": body.width() / 2 - loadingBox.width() / 2 + "px"
        });

        $scope.$on(eventsSvc.global.loadingBoxShow, function () {
            loadingBoxParent.addClass('global-spinner-visible');
        });

        $scope.$on(eventsSvc.global.loadingBoxHide, function() {
            loadingBoxParent.removeClass('global-spinner-visible');
        });
    }

    return loadingBoxDir;
});
```

And this is my interceptor:

```
    app.provider('httpInterceptorSvc', [function () {
    this.$get = function ($q, $rootScope, $injector, eventsSvc) {
        var httpInterceptorSvc = {};

        httpInterceptorSvc.request = function (requestParam) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast(eventsSvc.global.loadingBoxShow);
            return requestParam;
        }

        httpInterceptorSvc.response = function (responseParam) {
            hideLoadingBox();
            return responseParam;
        }

        httpInterceptorSvc.requestError = function (requestErrorParam) {
            hideLoadingBox();
            return $q.reject(requestErrorParam);
        }

        httpInterceptorSvc.responseError = function (responseErrorParam) {
            hideLoadingBox();
            return $q.reject(responseErrorParam);
        }

        function hideLoadingBox() {
            var $http = $injector.get('$http');
            if ($http.pendingRequests.length === 0) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast(eventsSvc.global.loadingBoxHide);
            }
        }

        return httpInterceptorSvc;
    }
}])
```

This is the events service:

```
    app.factory('eventsSvc', [function () {
    var eventsSvc = {
        global: {
            loadingBoxHide: 'global.loadingBox.hide',
            loadingBoxShow: 'global.loadingBox.show'
        }
    };

    return eventsSvc;
}])
```

Now as you can see in  the interceptor in both the request and response I am trying to broadcast to the loadingBoxDir. The problem is that the request broadcast does not reach the directive.

One interesting fact is that the response broadcast reaches the directive and I cannot figure out what is the difference between the two

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Also could you console.log something right before    $rootScope.$broadcast(eventsSvc.global.loadingBoxShow);

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem with the code.The ideea is that ajax calls get executed as soon as the page loads, but the directives did not have time to be initialized that's why when broadcast gets called it does not reach this on function:

```
$scope.$on(eventsSvc.global.loadingBoxShow, function () {
        loadingBoxParent.addClass('global-spinner-visible');
 });
```

In order to solve the problem I added this piece of code:

```
loadingBoxParent.addClass('global-spinner-visible');
```

What this does is sets the loading box visible as soon as the page loads which makes sense because I am executing ajax calls in the controller.